# Algorithm to propagate internal Physics force in a structure of building

Tags: physics, algorithm

**Scenario:**

A floating structure composes of many nodes (or in more visual meaning - a cubic block).

Every node is snapped to the same 3D grid. (similar to a minecraft castle)

There are external forces apply to each node at different values.

For example, node A receives force = Vec3(1,0,0) at time = 1s-3s, node B receives force = Vec3(0,1,0) at time 2s-4s.   Most external forces apply to center of mass of node.

Every pair of adjacent nodes (6 neighbors) is tied together by a "joint" i.e. glue.
Each joint can received some (but limited) pulling/pushing force/torque.

**Question:** 
How to calculate/approximate force of each and every joints?
I want to use them to break object apart / create some spark graphics.

**Maximum flow problem** is fast, but too limit for this case.  Although it is quite efficient to propagate force like fluid in pipe system, it don't support Torque and many sources/sinks.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem

**Networks of Torque Propagation** requires a solid ground, so it can't be used for this problem. 
http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~pablo/thesis/html/node29.html

**Bullet Physics Engine** : I tried to use its constraint, but for very high amount of nodes (400), they are not stable, i.e. become divergent & explode.

**My poor approach** : I initialized all force between joint = Vec3(0,0,0), and then use Newton Rules (F=ma & T=Ixw) to propagate force gradually in each iteration.  It always yields perfect result but take too much time (10+ ms), so it is unusable.

Note that the algorithm can provide non-optimal solution and can have some limitation (e.g. no torque).
Performance is important (500 nodes within 1-2 ms, C++).

Comment: 1. What interactions are expected in your scenario? 1.a Do you apply a force on an individual node or simultanesouly? 1.b Do you apply simultaneous forces in regions that are far apart (e.g. opposite sides of a cube?).
2. Do you want to implement this as a task (learning), or have you tried a Physics engine with unsatisfactory results?
3. What have you tried? (e.g. why do you refer to a maximum  flow approach)?
Possible solutions: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~cutler/classes/advancedgraphics/F05/lectures/12_rigid_body_deformation_fracture.pdf

Comment: Thank to mention about fracture in the link!  
I have updated my question to provide more information.